# Windows Explorer integrated application

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to write an application that will integrate into the windows explorer (As a dock or tab) ?

If it is, a few starting pointers would be welcome :)

Comment: What do you mean by "dock or tab"?

Comment: @selbie, I want to create an application that will look native inside the windows explorer. Maybe my terms are incorrect, I meant was a "pane" as in the "Organize" -> "Layout" -> "Preview Pane" in windows 7 windows explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want the general "shell extensions" API in Windows.

I recommend ordering one of the last remaining used copies of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861001843). (Windows Shell Programming by Dino Esposito).  It's an old text, but not much has changed in regards to shell extensions since it was written.  If I recall, it has a chapter on how to write a preview extension.

The MSDN reference on Shell APIs can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177(v=VS.85).aspx). IPreviewHandler might be an interface to look at.

Good luck and hope this helps.